# How to make one way platform on which i can come down if button pressed

Tags: java, libgdx, box2d

**So, what i want:**

- If my player's body linear velocity.y > 0 then move through platform.
- If my player's body colliding with platform and button "DOWN" pressed, move down through it

**What i've tried:**

```
switch (fixA.getFilterData().categoryBits | fixB.getFilterData().categoryBits) {
        case Game.PLATFORM_BIT | Game.PLAYER_BIT:
            if (playerBody == contactEntityA.getBody()) {
                if (playerBody.getBody().getPosition().y <
                        contactEntityB.getBody().getPosition().y + .5 || playerController.isDownPressed()) { // .5 is half height of platform body
                    contact.isEnabled = false;
                }
            } else {
                if (playerBody.getBody().getPosition().y <
                        contactEntityA.getBody().getPosition().y + .5 || playerController.isDownPressed()) { // .5 is half height of platform body
                    contact.isEnabled = false;
                }
            }
        break;
}
```

**My problem is:**

Box2d doesn't make contacts if body doesn't move for a few seconds. So after some time, contact doesn't occur and i can't move down.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple hack helped me. I'm just applying little velocity to a body each frame.

```
playerBody.applyLinearImpulse(0f, .000001f, .5f, .5f, true);
```

I'm not sure that is the best solution, write me please if you know how to do better.

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this:

```
object DisableContact: ContactListener {

    override fun beginContact(contact: Contact) {

    }

    override fun endContact(contact: Contact) {
    }

    override fun preSolve(contact: Contact, oldManifold: Manifold?) {

        val playerBody = contact.fixtureA.body!! // need to identify if fixtureA or fixtureB is the player body
        if (playerBody.linearVelocity.y < -3.5f) {
            contact.isEnabled = false
        }

    }

    override fun postSolve(contact: Contact, impulse: ContactImpulse?) {
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try sensors in box 2D so that it will not collide with any object and surely it will accept events.
when you need physical aspects then it is better to use box2D